# I have edited .profile , but os.environ doesn't see my variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, config, python-import

That is in .profile:

```
unset PRODROOT CONFROOT PYTHONPATH PYSRCROOT PYTHONCROOT
export PRODROOT=${PRODROOT:-/home/peter/Lv-164.UI/ecomap}
export PYSRCROOT=${PYSRCROOT:-${PRODROOT}/src/python}
export CONFROOT=${CONFROOT:-${PRODROOT}/etc}
export PYTHONPATH=${PRODROOT}/src/python
export PYTHON=${PYTHON:-/etc/python}
export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=${PYTHON_EGG_CACHE:-/tmp/.python-eggs}
```

That what I see in Ubuntu(14.04LTS) Terminal:

```
    >>> import os
    >>> "PRODROOT" in os.environ 
False
```

But once I have saw them in os.environ list.
I don't know what happened. I'm Newbie in Python,so don't be so severe.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: From the bash prompt, issue the command `echo $PRODROOT`, what do you see? If you don't see anything, you might want to source your .profile: `source ~/.profile`

Comment: Thanks to You all is working/

Comment: Side note: `${VAR:-value}` is superfluous for variables that you have just unset.

Comment: What's the difference between `-` and `~`?